# Reference a button ID within a class

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="dialogButtons" class="opportunityEditorPopup">     
    <span id="closed" class="label checkOption" style="display: none;"><input type="checkbox">Mark this as closed</span>
    <span class="testButtons" style="display: inline;">
            <button id="closeOpportunityButton" class="jqButton imaged ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" title="Close this opportunity" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button>
            <button id="newOrderButton" class="jqButton imaged ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" title="Raise New Quote" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">New Quote</span></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

So I currently have the following HTML and I am trying to reference the "closeOpportunityButton" in JQuery.

I am having trouble getting to this however, and have tried the following:

```
$('.testButtons #closeOpportunityButton').click(function(){
    console.log("test")
});
```

and

```
$('#dialogButtons .testButtons #closeOpportunityButton').click(function(){
    console.log("test")
});
```

Neither of which work.

Ideas?

Comment: IDs are unique so just `$("#closeOpportunityButton").on("click",function() { console.log("test") });` is enough

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/a83ov97r/. Check the console for underlying errors

Comment: As others have said ids are unique do you happen to have another Id=closeOpportunityButton somewhere in your document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use child selector in your selection. below is the code snippet:

```js
$('.testButtons > #closeOpportunityButton').click(function(){
    console.log("test")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="testButtons" style="display: inline;">
            <button id="closeOpportunityButton" class="jqButton imaged ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" title="Close this opportunity" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button>
            <button id="newOrderButton" class="jqButton imaged ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" title="Raise New Quote" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">New Quote</span></button>
    </span>
```